# How can I read the boolean value from litjson

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, litjson

[image]

My json file from server is like this:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"projectId":"572ca0cde163d","sensorId":"572ca2deea163b","createTime":1462514044,"updateTimeStamp":1462514044,"recognPicUrl":"http://192.168.1.115:8500/dddd.jpg","drawingModule":{"subjectTemplateId":"16","drawingUnits":[{"drawingUnitId":"572ca0c4f14c023cdeea163c",
"drawingResources":
[{"resourceUrl":"http://192.168.1.115:8300/dds.png","serviceProps":{},"resourceType":"IMG"}],"drawingComponentId":"1"}],
"templateConfig":{"isVertical":false}},"targetId":"ba0a0d83c657e49eb312"}}
```

How can I read the value "isVertical"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `Json` is **not** valid. There should be a '`:`' between `"serviceProps"` and `{},`.

Here is a fixed verision of your Json data.

```
{"status":"success","data":{"projectId":"572ca0cde163d","sensorId":"572ca2deea163b","createTime":1462514044,"updateTimeStamp":1462514044,"recognPicUrl":"http://192.168.1.115:8500/dddd.jpg","drawingModule":{"subjectTemplateId":"16","drawingUnits":[{"drawingUnitId":"572ca0c4f14c023cdeea163c",
"drawingResources":
[{"resourceUrl":"http://192.168.1.115:8300/dds.png","serviceProps":{},"resourceType":"IMG"}],"drawingComponentId":"1"}],
"templateConfig":{"isVertical":false}},"targetId":"ba0a0d83c657e49eb312"}}
```

To answer your question, you can easily extract `isVertical` by creating a class that represents all the keys then pull the `isVertical` from that class.

Unity add `Json` native support in **5.3** release. The solution below requires that you have 5.3 and above and it should work. Tested with **5.4.0b13** and it works Should work on **5.3**.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ServiceProps
{
}

[System.Serializable]
public class DrawingResource
{
    public string resourceUrl;
    public ServiceProps serviceProps;
    public string resourceType;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class DrawingUnit
{
    public string drawingUnitId;
    public List<DrawingResource> drawingResources;
    public string drawingComponentId;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TemplateConfig
{
    public bool isVertical;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class DrawingModule
{
    public string subjectTemplateId;
    public List<DrawingUnit> drawingUnits;
    public TemplateConfig templateConfig;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public string projectId;
    public string sensorId;
    public int createTime;
    public int updateTimeStamp;
    public string recognPicUrl;
    public DrawingModule drawingModule;
    public string targetId;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo
{
    public string status;
    public Data data;
}
```

Code to Read the `isVertical` Json value:

```
void test()
{
    string messageFromServer = "";
    messageFromServer = "{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"projectId\":\"572ca0cde163d\",\"sensorId\":\"572ca2deea163b\",\"createTime\":1462514044,\"updateTimeStamp\":1462514044,\"recognPicUrl\":\"http://192.168.1.115:8500/dddd.jpg\",\"drawingModule\":{\"subjectTemplateId\":\"16\",\"drawingUnits\":[{\"drawingUnitId\":\"572ca0c4f14c023cdeea163c\",\r\n    \"drawingResources\":\r\n    [{\"resourceUrl\":\"http://192.168.1.115:8300/dds.png\",\"serviceProps\":{},\"resourceType\":\"IMG\"}],\"drawingComponentId\":\"1\"}],\r\n    \"templateConfig\":{\"isVertical\":false}},\"targetId\":\"ba0a0d83c657e49eb312\"}}";



     PlayerInfo playerInfo;
     playerInfo = new PlayerInfo();
     playerInfo.data = new Data();
     playerInfo.data.drawingModule = new DrawingModule();

     playerInfo.data.drawingModule.drawingUnits = new List<DrawingUnit>();

     for (int i = 0; i < playerInfo.data.drawingModule.drawingUnits.Count; i++)
     {
         playerInfo.data.drawingModule.drawingUnits[i].drawingResources = new List<DrawingResource>();
     }


     playerInfo.data.drawingModule.templateConfig = new TemplateConfig();


     playerInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(messageFromServer);
     Debug.Log("Status: " + playerInfo.status);
     Debug.Log("Vertical: " + playerInfo.data.drawingModule.templateConfig.isVertical);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you !,it works in unity5.3.4. but for some complex reason we have to use unity5.2 version in our project. can you help me change it in Litjson way ? thanks for your reply.

Comment: @QibiaoTu I don't use Litjson. Why can't you use 5.3.4? Try replacing `playerInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(messageFromServer);`  with  `playerInfo  = JsonMapper.ToObject<PlayerInfo>(messageFromServer);`. It might work. Not sure since I hate external libraries. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
// read your json data into a variable
var jsonData = {"status":"success","data":{"projectId":"572ca0cde163d","sensorId":"572ca2deea163b","createTime":1462514044,"updateTimeStamp":1462514044,"recognPicUrl":"http://192.168.1.115:8500/dddd.jpg","drawingModule":{"subjectTemplateId":"16","drawingUnits":[{"drawingUnitId":"572ca0c4f14c023cdeea163c",
                "drawingResources":[{"resourceUrl":"http://192.168.1.115:8300/dds.png","serviceProps"{},"resourceType":"IMG"}],"drawingComponentId":"1"}],
                "templateConfig":{"isVertical":false}},"targetId":"ba0a0d83c657e49eb312"}};   

//then read it like this
var isVertical = jsonData.templateConfig.isVertical
```

**Edit**

It should be this in the way you want it

```
bool isVertical = (bool)jsondata["drawingModule"]["templateConfig"]["isVertical"];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.but I still can't get the value. i can get the "subjectTemplateId" like this:JsonData jsondata = JsonMapper.ToObject(configuration_json);
  string TemID = (string)jsondata["data"]["drawingModule"]["subjectTemplateId"]; in the same way I can't get the "isVertical" value,like this:  JsonData jsondata = JsonMapper.ToObject(configuration_json);
  bool isVertical = (bool)jsondata["data"]["drawingModule"]["templateConfig"]["isVertical"];

Comment: One moment, your json is not proper, I just check it here http://jsonlint.com/, it has errors

Comment: Your `"serviceProps" {},` doesn't have colon. Is it a typo or this is the exact data coming from server?

Comment: Thanks , I use bool isVertical = (bool)jsondata["templateConfig"]["isVertical"];but it still not work.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot explain you anymore I already explained you that you have problem with this part of your json `"serviceProps" {},`